# How to display two input value in the single field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three fields which are `firstname`, `lastname` and `fullname`.

What I am doing is, I have to display the firstname and lastname value in the fullname input field.

Forexample, I enter **firstname: Alpha** and **lastname: Gama** so I have to display the **fullname:Alpha Gama**.

I tried below code which is working for firstname only.

Would you help me out?

```js
$("#firstname").change(function() {
  $("#fullname").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname">

<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So read the last name field and append that to the end..... Seems like you are overthinking it....

Comment: @epascarello, Actually, I have more than 20 fields and their user enter the first name and last name. So i don't want to enter twice same data so I have to display the firstname and lastname in full name  field.

Comment: I know..... Saying you are overthinking it... it is very easy. You read both fields and set it... Read both values and add them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet, hope it helps:

```js
function updateFullName() {
    $("#fullname").val($("#firstname").val()+ ' ' + $("#lastname").val());
}

$("#firstname, #lastname").on('input', updateFullName);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="lastname">

<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
$("#firstname").change(function() {
    var firstName = $(this).val();
    var lastName = $("#lastname").val();
    var fullName = firstName;
    if(lastName !== "") fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    $("#fullname").val(fullName);
});

$("#lastName").change(function() {
    var firstName = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastName = $(this).val();
    var fullName = lastName;
    if(firstName !== "") fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    $("#fullname").val(fullName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```js
var firstName = "", lastName = "", fullName = "";
$("#firstname").keyup(function() {
  firstName = $(this).val();
  fullName = firstName+ " " +lastName;
  $("#fullname").val(fullName);
});
$("#lastname").keyup(function() {
  lastName = $(this).val();
  fullName = firstName+ " " +lastName;
  $("#fullname").val(fullName);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname" id="lastname">

<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, you can use jQuery "change" or "keydown" function instead of "keyup" function.